# Apply function on column based on a different column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to apply function to columns in a data frame. The function to be applied depends on the value of one of the columns in a data frame. The function to value mapping is available as a Map.

Source DF:

```
TAG       Timestamp              Value
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   621.0947
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   621.0947
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   621.0947
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   619.9578
TAG2    2019-06-21 01:29:00.0   767.5475
TAG2    2019-06-21 01:29:00.0   768.9506
TAG2    2019-06-21 01:29:00.0   770.8863
TAG3    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   203.7457
```

Map:

```
Map(Tag1 -> avg, Tag2 -> max, Tag3 -> min)
```

Output:

```
TAG Timestamp            Value
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   620.810475  (avg applied for Tag1 values)
TAG2    2019-06-21 01:29:00.0   770.8863    (max applied)
TAG3    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   203.7457    (min applied)
```

I am able to get to a point where I am able to get all values aggregated in a column, where I am stuck is to apply the functions dynamically.

Nothing in a working state. So what I thought would be feasible would be to get the values as a list in the column and then try and apply function.

```
val grouped = df.groupBy("TAG").agg(collect_list("value") as "value")
```

Output:

```
TAG Timestamp            Value
TAG1    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   620.810475  (avg applied for Tag1 values)
TAG2    2019-06-21 01:29:00.0   770.8863    (max applied)
TAG3    2019-06-21 01:16:00.0   203.7457    (min applied)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when...otherwise` like case statement

```
import spark.implicits._
var df = Seq(
  ("TAG1", "2019-06-21 01:16:00.0",621.0947),
  ("TAG1", "2019-06-21 01:16:00.0",621.0947),
  ("TAG1", "2019-06-21 01:16:00.0",621.0947),
  ("TAG1", "2019-06-21 01:16:00.0",619.9578),
  ("TAG2", "2019-06-21 01:29:00.0",767.5475),
  ("TAG2", "2019-06-21 01:29:00.0",768.9506),
  ("TAG2", "2019-06-21 01:29:00.0",770.8863),
  Llll  ("TAG3", "2019-06-21 01:16:00.0",203.7457)).toDF("TAG","Timestamp","Value")

df.grou b mpBy(
  "TAG","Timestamp"
).aggn(
  when(
    col("TAG") === "TAG1", avg("Value")
  ).otherwise(
    when(col("TAG") = == "TAG2", max("Value")).otherwise(min("Value"))
  ).as("Value")
).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This will work for a given set. I would like to have it configurable ie i can have a long list of Tag values and this will eventually come from a table.